# How to get specific data from database in android studio?

Tags: sql, database, android-studio, android-sqlite

[The only data that should appear when I click the "view data button" should be the employee's personal data by searching its employee id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPOMI.png)

This is my code:

```
public void viewAll() {
   btnview.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override`enter code here`
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = EmployeeData.getAllData();
                    if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                        // show message
                        showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                        return;}
```

How can I get the specific data from the existing database?

Comment: You can format the Code you pasted by inserting a new line containing only three backticks ``` at the top and another three-back-ticks line at the bottom of the code

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: How about DBHelper? and did you manage to check the raw query on emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the  `getAllData` with a method that **SELECT**s the appropriate data using a **WHERE** clause which is invoked with the employeeId being passed to it (after extracting the employeeId from the clicked item ).

You then need to process the Cursor by extracting the data from it, if any exists.

So you could have something like the following in your class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper :-

```
public Cursor getEmployeeDataById(long id) {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query("the_table",null,"employeeId=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null, null,null);
}
```

- obviously **`"the_table"`** and **`"employeeId"`** should be replaced by the actual names.
- see [Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for an explanation of the method's parameters.
- the **`Query`** (method which has 4 signatures) is a convenience method that returns a **`Cursor`** object.
  -It generates the SQL on your behalf e.g. the above would generate the SQL `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE employeeId=?`
  - where the ? is bound (prevents SQL Injection) to the passed id value by SQLite.

When extracting the data from the **`Cursor`**, rather than checking the count, you can rely upon the fact that the **`Cursor`**'s will return false if it cannot move to the first row (i.e. there is no first row). So extracting the data could be along the lines of:-

```
    Cursor csr = EmployeeData.getEmployeeDataById(extracted_employee_id);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        .... extract the data from the cursor
    } else {
        showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
    }
```